# Unknown URLs reported as 404 in Google Search Console

Tags: http-status-code-404, google-search-console, google-crawlers

I am facing an issue that Google Bot is reporting some unknown URLs ([as highlighted in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hu74.jpg)) from one type of page. After checking the source code, JS and CSS files I have not come across any such URLs. Because of them the 404 count reported by Google Search Console is continuously increasing.
Can anyone please, guide me in finding the root cause as to why crawler is reporting such URLs or how to avoid them.

Comment: Click on each link in Search Console and it should tell where it's linked from. Might be a mistake that's been rectified in which case they will eventually die out. Can take a few months.

Comment: All such URLs are reported to come from corresponding URLs from my website where we have a valid ID in place of the symbol " [ "

Answer (score 0):

Most of the cases, these URLs are coming from outside backlinks to your website, check your backlinks from "Links to my site"

Or maybe your domain was on another website and your bought it.

Also check if you have spammy comments on your website.